# optimizing UNNEST intarray with GROUP BY for postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, relational-database

I am trying to GROUP BY array values of a column, here is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."modifier_arrays" ( 
   "id" INTEGER DEFAULT nextval('modifier_arrays_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
   "product_id" INTEGER NOT NULL, 
   "modifier_ids" INTEGER[] NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( "id" )
);
CREATE INDEX "modifier_ids_btree" ON "public"."modifier_arrays" USING btree( "modifier_ids" ASC NULLS LAST );
CREATE INDEX "modifier_ids_gin" ON "public"."modifier_arrays" USING gin( "modifier_ids" );
```

I filled it up with 500K rows and here is the query that I am running:

```
SELECT UNNEST(modifier_ids) AS modifier_id FROM modifier_arrays WHERE '{}' <@ modifier_ids   GROUP BY UNNEST(modifier_ids);
```

and here is the analyze explain:

```
HashAggregate (cost=51563.39..52068.64 rows=10000 width=43) (actual time=8705.943..8705.962 rows=101 loops=1)
   -> Bitmap Heap Scan on modifier_arrays (cost=34387.54..51061.89 rows=200600 width=43)         (actual time=1683.227..5771.153 rows=10998944 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ('{}'::integer[] <@ modifier_ids)
   -> Bitmap Index Scan on modifier_ids_gin (cost=0.00..34387.04 rows=2006 width=0) (actual time=1676.215..1676.215 rows=2000000 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ('{}'::integer[] <@ modifier_ids)
   Total runtime: 8706.327 ms
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
SET work_mem = '550MB';
SET cpu_tuple_cost = 0.1;
SET enable_seqscan = OFF;
```

Oh and this is my Postgres version:

```
PostgreSQL 9.1.14
```

I am still not able get it down to an acceptable performance, how can I optimize this query? I am out of ideas/google keywords :(

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to achieve with these actions?

Comment: I don't get the query.  Why are you using `WHERE '{}' <@ modifier_ids`?  What's it supposed to do?  Doesn't '{}' evaluate to the numeric value of the brace characters in this comparison?  And does not '<@' mean less than the absolute value?  Are there implicit or explicit connotations of these strings and operators that I am missing?  And I see that you are UNNESTing, but where is the array creation happening?

Comment: @vyegorov: I am trying to GROUP BY the elements of the array, for ex:
1 | {3, 4}
2 | {4, 5}

I want to have a result like:
(4, 2)
(3, 1)
(5, 1)

Comment: @bf2020: As the structure of the table says, the modifier_ids is an intarray, that is the array and WHERE '{}' <@ modifier_ids is just an empty query that matches all of the array. If I want to match specific arrays I would then change the query to '{1,3}' <@ modifier_ids

Comment: @bf2020: [The PostgreSQL array operator "<@"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) means "is contained by".

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, after doing a lot of inserts/updates to the table, I ran the query and it was really slow, what I needed to do was VACUUM ANALYZE the table. There's an AUTOVACUUM settings somewhere that I missed ...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not doing anything with the aggregate you can just select distinct

```
select distinct unnest(modifier_ids) as modifier_id
from modifier_arrays
where '{}' <@ modifier_ids;
```